# Node.js 8.9.1 debugging not working with Netbeans 8.2

Tags: node.js, debugging, netbeans-8

I'm trying to setup a node.js project with netbeans, and everything seemed to go well and as documented until i wanted to try out the debugger...
After a while of googling i found a not responded to post on the Netbeans forums:

https://forums.netbeans.org/topic67911.html

This is exactly the problem i am having as well.

Does anybody have some information or a workaround or any way to make the debugger work?

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue - when I try to debug Node 8.9.3 in Netbeans 8.2 (patch 2), I get the following error: `(node:1935) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: 'node --debug' and 'node --debug-brk' are invalid. Please use 'node --inspect' or 'node --inspect-brk' instead.`  Is it possible to somehow change the command Netbeans uses to launch the debugger?

Comment: Yep that's the same i was getting, tried to find where to change the command but couldn't find it.

Comment: I've created a wrapper Batch Script to replace the calling argument --debug-brk with --inspect-brk, without success ...

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 8.2 only supports the now deprecated V8 debugging protocol.
Details here:- https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#legacy-debugger.

Node v7 is the last version to support V8 debugging.
Downloads:  https://nodejs.org/download/release/v7.10.1/